# Split binary string to grouped digits

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have this format of string: `110001101` and I would like to split that `string` to `string[]` by grouped chunks of `1`s or `0`s.

So from that string I would get splitted `string[] = { "11", "000", "11", "0", "1" };`

Is it possible to achieve that with Regex, I don't know where to start? Or should I find another solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capturing mechanism and use `Regex.Split` with a mere `(0+)` regex like this:

```
var txt5 = "110001101";
var res5 = Regex.Split(txt5, @"(0+)").Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p)).ToArray();
```

Result:

[image]

This will work as you do not have symbols other than `0` or `1` in your input string, and the captured text is also output as array elements. The LINQ code helps eliminate any unwelcome empty elements from the resulting array (as is the case with `0`s only).

Answer (score 3):

So you want either consecutive zeros (`0+`) or consecutive ones (`1+`). Just iterate over the matches:

```
0+|1+
```